# jquery overriding (rather Removing) my button disable attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a unusual problem with jquery overriding or rather removing my button disabled attribute making it enable.

1. I have a table with n rows with pagination.
2. If an error occurs in any of the row, I am disabling save button
   using

> ```
>  function disableButton(){
>          var data = customobj.grid('data');       
>     if (data.length > 0) {
>         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
>             var errorFlag = data[i].error;
>           var errorFlagNrc = data[i].errorNrc;
>             if ((errorFlag == "false" || errorFlag == "") &&  (errorFlagNrc == "false" || errorFlagNrc == "")) {
>               $("#save").removeAttr("disabled");
>             } else {                    
>                 $("#save").attr("disabled", "disabled");
>                return;
>             }
>         }
>      }
>     }
> ```

Now when I click on pagination arrow next set of rows loads and I am calling this function to disable the button if an error exists which is working fine and button is getting disabled but before page loads the control goes to `jquery 1.11` code below which remove my disabled attribute making the button enable again.

```
if ( !(eventHandle = elemData.handle) ) {
            eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {
                // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
                // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
                return typeof jQuery !== strundefined && (!e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type) ?
                    jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
                    undefined;
            };
            // Add elem as a property of the handle fn to prevent a memory leak with IE non-native events
            eventHandle.elem = elem;


}
```

I am not sure why this is happening? Anybody have any idea?

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: how do you load next page? do you use another url or you loading it via ajax?

Comment: No it's just the table with tbody is getting created with new data; I am on the same URL

Comment: I am not sure that if I can reproduce this in fiddle....